# Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver

Tags: c#, nhibernate, sqlite

Here's the code that raises the exception

```
   public Configuration GetConfiguration()
    {
        var persister = SQLiteConfiguration
            .Standard
            .UsingFile("Test.db")
            .ShowSql();


        var configuration = Fluently
            .Configure()
            .Database(persister)
            .Mappings(map => map.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<WordMap>())
            .BuildConfiguration();

        new SchemaExport(configuration).Execute(true, true, false);

        return configuration;

    }
```

The full exception text:

> Failure: NHibernate.HibernateException : Could not create the driver
>   from NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver, NHibernate, Version=2.1.2.4000,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4.
>
> ----> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> ----> NHibernate.HibernateException : The IDbCommand and IDbConnection implementation in the assembly System.Data.SQLite could
>   not be found. Ensure that the assembly System.Data.SQLite is located
>   in the application directory or in the Global Assembly Cache. If the
>   assembly is in the GAC, use  element in the
>   application configuration file to specify the full name of the
>   assembly.

Version of NHibernate is 2.1.2.4000
Version of System.Data.SQLite is 1.0.66.0
Target Framework is 3.5 (x86)
Local copy for System.Data.SQLite is ON.

What may be wrong?

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845490/fluentnhibernate-and-sqlite http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460045/sql-data-sqllite-version-with-nhibernate-2-1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041271/how-to-configure-sqlite-to-run-with-nhibernate-where-assembly-resolves-system-dat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got rid of this issue by adding useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" to app.config. See [Problem Upgrading NHibernate SQLite Application to .Net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627145/problem-upgrading-nhibernate-sqlite-application-to-net-4-0)

Answer (score 13):

Just copy **System.Data.SQLite.dll** library to the the base directory of your application (especially where NHibernate.dll library is placed).
You even don't need it to add as reference under VS.

Regards
Bronek

Comment: Installing System.Data.SQLite nuget package also make it works.

Comment: FYI, it's:  Installing the System.Data.SQLite.Core package, which adds the System.Data.SQLite reference also makes it work.  (i.e. you don't need all of the other stuff... like EF6 support... that comes with the System.Data.SQLite package.)

Answer (score 11):

I just installed the SQLite NuGet package and that worked for me.

Answer (score 6):

Could not create the driver from NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver, NHibernate, Version=2.1.2.4000, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aa95f207798dfdb4

Solution:

testsettings:
choose hosts
choose run tests in 64 bit process on 64 bit machine

hoping I could help.

merry coding

Answer (score 2):

If LocalCopy is on, is it on for a version of System.Data.SQLite in the start-up project because that's where it'll be looking for it, not in the bin directory of a sub-project.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2019, in **Test -> Processor Architecture for AnyCPU Projects**, I changed from x64 to **Auto** and it solved my problem.